# What will Jannah be like?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, jannah, akhirah

Based on the hadith, in Jannah, you will have everlasting happiness and you will get anything you want. But the real question is, what happens if two people have contradictory desires? For example, two people see a tree with green leaves. The first guy wishes the green leaves turn yellow. But the second guy wishes that the leaves stay green. What happens then?

And also, will we have our haram worldly desires in Jannah? For example, let's say I was sadistic and I have this intense desire to hurt people for my own pleasure. But just for the sake of Allah, I refrain from hurting people. Will I be able to fulfill my sadistic desires in Jannah?

I always had my own theory of what Jannah might be like. According to my theory, everyone in Jannah will be living in their own "bubble" or in other words, their own "dimension". So if you see someone you know, then that's not really the actual person. That's just a "copy" of that person living in your dimension. So if you kill that person, he/she is not really dead. It just means that the person got wiped out of your dimension. The real person however, is just living in their own dimension. But this is just a theory I came up with.

Comment: We only know that janah is different what we've seen or known here on earth so logically disputes won't exist there!

Answer (score -1):

No one knows but Allah how Jannah is gonna be like.
There are Ayats of Qur'An and Sahih Hadiths for us in this wordly life to just create a 'understanding' and a 'vision' of Jannah .
I believe its gonna be WONDERFUL but may Allah bestow on us His Mercy so we can get in Jannah in shaa Allah and never doubt that you are going to be disatisfied and bored in Jannah since Allah says :
' They will abide therein forever and no change will they wish for'
Just Imagine for a moment how life could be without getting old , no worries , no illnes , no disorders , no boreness , no dirt(no call of nature), always smelling good , having sweat of musk esence , no sleep , no envy , no hatred , no jealosy , eating fruits and whatever you desire , having chaste and gaze lowers of Hooris female / or male(in case of sisters since Allah says : They going to have whatever they wish for) , no occupations(jobs) , living for ever not worrying about death ,  getting beautified every Friday (Jummah) , living in Palaces and Mansion made by bricks of gold and sivler , wearing gold (neckles , rings etc) visiting the noble prophets from Adam a.s to Muhammed a.s , asking them and having cobversations , meeting the Sahabahs and Tabeeins , meeting scholars and fighters in the path of Allah ,enjoying the bliss gardens of Allah that no one can ever imagine , worshipping Allah in Jannah , seeing His Majesty's Face full of Nur in there on top of all , what more can anyone wish for ? Just seeing Allah and worshipping Him in that state it is more Honouralbe than all above what was mention .
I ask Allah to bestow His mercy upon us , and to wait us on the Day of Account with His Smile being Pleased with us .
Just get to Jannah in shaa Allah , you will never wish anything else .